# what permissions does my canvas app need to post to the feed on its own page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, user-permissions

The page that I'm starting as a compliment to my canvas app is one where a certain user action will add a post to the feed of that page. I know that if I want to post to a page that the user personally administers, I have to get the manage_pages permission, but no one administers this page but me as the developer, so why would I ask the user for that permission? So aside from the publish_stream permission what do I need to do to make this work? 
This isn't something I can do in open graph because you can only post open graph stories to the users own feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require **no** permission **if you want to post on your page** on user's behalf. You just require to retrieve and save your Page's `access token`, retrieved by your extended access token with `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permission so that it doesn't expires, and use the same to post on your page.

If you want the same to be posted on the user's timeline then you may ask for the `publish_stream` permission from the user to post on his timeline.

Just as a word of **caution**, you should moderate the content that would be posted on your Page's wall just to be sure, so that your Page is not filled with spam posts.